# Does exist typed query in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, types

In JPA exists typed query:

TypedQuery q;

Does exist similar in hibernate?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you find one in the API doc: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/classic/Session.html ? What do you conclude?

Comment: there is nothing about typedquery. You have made a mistake. Did you tried F3 - typedquery ?

Comment: Yes indeed, there is nothing about TypedQuery. What do you conclude (other than me doing a mistake)?